# Relation between subgroups of a cyclic group of order $p^n.$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite cyclic group of order $p^n$, where $p$ is a prime and $n \geq 0 .$ If $H \& K$ are subgroups of $G$, then show that either $H \subset K$ or $K \subset H.$

My attempt
Let $G$ be of order $p^n$ and let $a$ be one of it's generator i.e $G=\langle a\rangle.$ Since $G$ is cyclic, so are $H$ and $K$. Let $|H|=p^h$ and $|K|=p^k$ (We know that order should be of this form due to Langrange's theorem). Without loss of generality assume $h \le k$. We wish to show that $H \subset K$.
When $h=k$ this is true since there is only one subgroup of order $p^h$.
Can you complete the proof when $h < k$. If you have another approach, please post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First method :** The subgroups $H$ and $K$ are respectively generated by $a^{p^{n-h}}$ and $a^{p^{n-k}}$. But if $h \leq k$ then $p^{n-k}$ divides $p^{n-h}$. So $H \leq K$.

**Second method :** Since $K$ is cyclic of order $p^k$ and $h \leq k$, $K$ contains a unique subgroup $H'$ of order $p^h$. But $H'$ is also a subgroup of $G$, so by unicity $H'=H$.

Answer (score 1):

The lattice of subgroups of a cyclic group of order $n$ is isomorphic to the lattice of divisors of $n$. When $n$ is a power of a prime, this lattice is a chain and "divides" then becomes the same as "less than or equal to".